# How to use devtool add command to auto generate recipes with our local own source code

Tags: yocto-recipe

It seems yocto devtool add command works based on the remote git to fetch the source code, but sometimes we may need to use our own local source code to generate recipes, it may be without git and just the source code on the local folder, is there any suggestion for using devtool add to generate recipes with our source code?

Thanks.
Regards,
Jack

I used devtool add command to generate the recipe with our source code folder:
devtool add recipe_name source_code_folder_path
the bb file SRC_URI = "", and when use devtool finish recipe_name meta_folder_path, it will show error below:

bb.process.ExecutionError: Execution of 'git rev-parse --show-toplevel' failed with exit code 128:
fatal: not a git repository (or any parent up to mount point /)
Stopping at filesystem boundary (GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not set).